# Proving that cosets partition a group

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have read from multiple sources the statement that the two statements are equivalent:

1. If H is a subgroup of G then the left cosets of H in G partition G
2. Let $g_1H, g_2H$ be two cosets of $H$ in $G$. Then either $g_1H \cap g_2H = \emptyset$ or $g_1H = g_2H$.

I understand the proof for the second statement, but I'm not completely sure as to why it is equivalent to the first.

What if there are insufficient cosets of $H$ in $G$ for their union to make up $G$?

Comment: If $G$ has order $12$ and $H \le G$ has order $2$ then there will be $6$ left-cosets of $H$ in $G$.

Comment: If $G$ is finite then any subgroup has size (order) a divisor of the order of $G.$ The total number of cosets, including the subgroup itself, is just the quotient.

Comment: @Clive is pointing out that $1H = H$ is a coset that needs to be included; it should at least clear up your divisibility confusion.

Comment: Edited the question, please have a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What if there are insufficient cosets of $H$ in $G$ for their union to make up $G$?

Not possible. Each element $g\in G$ is contained in the coset $gH$.

Answer (score 1):

The cosets of $H$ partition $G$ because they are the equivalence classes of the relation $$a \sim b \iff a^{-1}b \in H$$ and we know that the equivalence classes of a relation on a set partition the set.

We can verify that this is an equivalence relation:

- Reflexive: $g\sim g$ because $gH=gH$.
- Symmetric: $a \sim b \implies a^{-1}b \in H \implies a^{-1}b=h$ for some $h \in H.$
  Taking inverses, we get $b^{-1}a = h^{-1} \in H$
- Transitive: Suppose $a \sim b$ and $b \sim c$, meaning $a^{-1}b \in H$ and $b^{-1}c \in H$.
  Then $a^{-1}bb^{-1}c = a^{-1}c \in H$, so $a \sim c$.

**EDIT:** There cannot be insufficient cosets of $H$ in $G$ for their union to make up $G$ because of the definition of partition: the union of the equivalence classes *has* to equal the whole set.